# next.js, Emotion-styled(Styled-Component) does not work at initial rendering in mobile

Tags: next.js, mobile, media-queries, styled-components, react-props

everyone.
i'm using `next.js`, `emotion/styled`, `react-responsive` in my project.

when running on a desktop browser, the style works normally.
The style works normally even if it's re-rendered like page switching.

However
**when running on a mobile browser, the style does not apply.**

**I think the problem is that the media query is applied before the browser checks the viewport.**

i'm using meta tag

```js
// rootLayout.jsx
import Head from "next/head"

<Head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</Head>
```

I want to know what the problem is. 
The code I used is as follows.

---

#### my code

- mediaquery custom hook

```js
import { useMediaQuery } from "react-responsive"

export const useIsMobile = () => {
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: "(max-width: 767px)" })
  return isMobile
}
```

- Issue.tsx

```js
import { useIsMobile } from "@/hooks/useMediaQuery"
export default function Issue() {
  const isMobile = useIsMobile()
  return (
    <Div isMobile={isMobile}>
       hello!:)
    </Div>
  )
}
const Div = styled.div<{ isMobile?: boolean }>`
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  padding: ${(props) => (props.isMobile ? "20px" : "0")}; // 20px not applied in mobile browser
`
```

---

// my version in package.json

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@fontsource/noto-sans": "^5.0.18",
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-responsive": "^9.0.2"
  },
```

---

#### The method I used to solve this problem :

1. **Rendering components after mount**
   I gave my browser time to check the viewport.
   In this method, the style works normally.
   But there is a problem that I have to use all of the components in the problem.

```js
  const [isMount, setIsMount] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMount(true)
  }, [])

  if (!isMount) return null
```

2. **Modifying media query hook**
   This method causes the browser to flicker

```js
export const useIsMobile = () => {
  const [isMount, setIsMount] = useState(false)
  const isMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: "(max-width: 767px)" })

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMount(true)
  }, [])

  return isMount ? isMobile : undefined
}
```

---

thank you